# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'spam' was never awaited spam(channel) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord.py

so i tried to make a spam function and run it but it just gives this error: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'spam' was never awaited
spam(channel)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
and no message is being sent.

this is the code:

```
await guild.create_text_channel("NEEDLESS-NUKER")
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                date = str(datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
                date = date.split(" ")[1]
            amount = 500
            for i in range(amount):
                await guild.create_text_channel(random.choice(SPAM_CHANNEL))
                spam(channel)
            date = str(datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
            date = date.split(" ")[1]
            print(f"{c.YELLOW}[{date}]{c.GREEN} Nuked {guild.name} Successfully.")
            return

async def spam(channel):
    for i in range(15):
        try:
            names = json.loads(open("words.json").read())
            SPAM_MESSAGE = [
                "@everyone LOL GET NUKED :skull::skull:",
                "@everyone LOL IMAGINE GETTING NUKED :skull::skull:",
                "lol hahaha get nuked",
                f"im {random.choice(names)}",
                f"Lol this is so random like {random.choice(names)}#{random.randint(1, 1000)} :skull:",
                f"Made By {random.choice(names)}!",
            ]
            msg = random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE)
            await channel.send(msg)
            date = str(datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
            date = date.split(" ")[1]
            print(f"{c.YELLOW}[{date}]{c.GREEN} Succeffully send {msg}")
        except Exception as e:
            names = json.loads(open("words.json").read())
            SPAM_MESSAGE = [
                "@everyone LOL GET NUKED JOIN https://dsc.gg/pythondevs",
                "@everyone LOL IMAGINE GETTING NUKED :skull::skull:",
                "@everyone https://dsc.gg/pythondevs",
                f"@everyone im {random.choice(names)}",
                f"@everyone Lol this is so random like {random.choice(names)}!{random.randint(1000, 10000)}",
                f"@everyone Made By {random.choice(names)}!",
            ]
            msg = random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE)
            date = str(datetime.now()).split(".")[0]
            date = date.split(" ")[1]
            print(f"{c.YELLOW}[{date}]{c.RED} Failed Sending Message {msg} exc: {e}")
```

first it was @client.event and then on_guild_channel_create(channel) and it worked but now it wont work i changed it because everytime i created a channel with this bot it would send 15 messages in the channel and if i make a voice channel it just gives me an error.

so please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](/tour) Always read the error and try googling before asking similar questions. Add `await` before `spam(channel)` to make it `await spam(channel)`. Does it work after adding `await`?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder Thanks for the anser i have used google too search it up but couldnt find any ansers now it works Thanks for helping me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling an async function, so you need to create_task it or await it.

```
import asyncio
import time


async def wait:
    time.sleep(1)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return None


result = asyncio.create_task(wait()) #Wait 1 second.
await wait() #Wait 2 seconds because it will wait for execution to end.
```

In your case, you would need to change line 8 from (8th line of the answer)

```
spam(channel)
```

to

```
await spam(channel)
```